# How to import module correct in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
I have a declared module:

declare module conflicts {

  export interface Item {}

  export interface Item2 {}

  export interface Item3 {}
```

}

I tried ti import this module in component like:

```
import * from '../../../_models/conflicts/conflicts';
```

Then use it:

```
let c = {} as conflicts.item3;
```

But it does not work

Comment: It should be: `export declare module conflicts {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module declaration should look like the following:

```
export declare module Conflicts {

  export interface Item {}

  export interface Item2 {}

  export interface Item3 {}
}
```

The import should be:

`import * as conflicts from '../../../_models/conflicts/conflicts';`

Then, to use the import, do this:

`let c = {} as conflicts.Conflicts.Item3;`

Notes:

- `conflicts` with a lower-case 'c' in the usage is basically the
  contents of the import.
- `Conflicts` with a capital 'C' in the usage
  is the module itself.
- Be sure you capitalize the 'I' of 'Item3' to
  match the interface declaration in the module.
- In the `as conflicts` part of the import, you can really change `conflicts` to anything you want. This is just for setting how the import will be referred to in the rest of the file.

Comment: Please do not post something as an answer that you believe or think it works. If you don't now either test it are try to write it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @PinkieSwirl. I've now tested my solution and made some corrections. I'll be sure to do that before I post an answer in the future.